# C++ moving characters from one vector to another

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I am trying to create a program that reads a file named `symbols.txt`, fill a vector with the symbols, then take chars that are in the range `[d;p]` and move them to the second vector while erasing them from the first vector.

```cpp
int main(){
    vector<char> sym1;
    vector<char> sym2;
    int p = 100, d = 80;
    char x;
    ifstream symbols("symbols.txt");
    while (symbols >> x )
    {
        sym1.push_back(x);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < sym1.size(); i++){
        if (sym1[i] < p && sym1[i] > d){
            sym2.push_back(sym1[i]);
            sym1.erase(sym1.begin()+i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this, the program works if there are no characters the same, otherwise it only moves half of the characters and leaves the other half untouched.

Comment: Why are you using a vector and not a string from the string header?

Comment: @Dock in this program i'm also trying to print the symbols in 7 columns and i thought it would be easier to do that with vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your implementation, the first thing you need to notice is that in your `for` loop, `sym1.size()` changes if you call `sym1.erase()`. Second, since your variable `i` increments every time, you skip some elements in the vector.

For example, the element at index 5 is erased, then the element at index 6 will move down to replace it. In the mean time, your loops does `i++`, so you skip the element that moved to index 5.

I think you should use iterators with C++ containers, below is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> sym1;
    vector<char> sym2;
    int p = 100, d = 80;
    char x;
    // ifstream symbols("symbols.txt");
    // while (symbols >> x)
    // {
    //     sym1.push_back(x);
    // }
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        sym1.push_back(i);
    }
    int size = sym1.size();
    for(vector<char>::iterator it = sym1.begin(); it != sym1.end(); ){
        if (*it < p && *it > d){
            sym2.push_back(*it);
            it = sym1.erase(it);
        }
        else
            it++;
    }
    for(vector<char>::iterator it = sym2.begin(); it != sym2.end(); it++) {
        cout << (int)*it << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: i modified my code as such 
`for(vector<char>::iterator it=sym1.begin();it!=sym1.end();){
  if(*it < p && *it > d){sym2.push_back(*it); it = sym1.erase(it);} else it++;}
` and it works now but i need to do more research on iterators because i don't fully understand why it works

Comment: Find out how c++ container and iterator works! In your case, maybe you can also try [lower_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) & [upper_bound](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/).

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is good for a lot of things. However, it's terribly inefficient when it comes to insertion or erasing at any other position than the end.

When an element is inserted somewhere (not at end), then the following happens:

- The internally managed size is increased by 1. (This may cause a re-allocation of the internal buffer.)
- The last element is moved to next position, the second last element is moved to the now "free" position, and so on until the element at insertion index is moved.

Similar happens when an element is erased:

- The successor of the element to erase is moved to its previous position, the next is moved to its previous position, and so on until the last element is moved.
- Finally, the internally managed size is decreased by 1. (No re-allocation. – The buffer is kept as reserved.)

In OPs case, it's the repeated erasing which makes me concerns. And, when I had this problem in production I used a way to reduce all the moves to the absolutely minimal required.

For this, I use two indices:

- one to read and check the characters
- one to write the characters which have to be kept in the vector (`sym1` in OPs sample).

While the read index is simply incremented for each loop iteration (as usual) the write index is incremented only after an element has been moved (because it should be kept).
As long as nothing is erased, both indices will have identical values. In this case, it's a bit annoying that elements are moved to the position where they already are. However, I consider this as the lesser evil. (Checking whether indices are still identical will probably buy nothing if the *move* is simple enough.) As soon as something is erased the write index starts to lag behind the read index.

So finally, for a vector of length N there are exactly N write operations to perform (and this for granted). This sounds reliable and not too terrible.

(Erasing elements individually one by one could be in worst case result in
N - 1 + N - 2 + … + 1 moves of elements which are roughly N * (N - 1) / 2 or (N² - N) / 2.)

For the demonstration, the modified sample of OP:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> sym1, sym2;
  const char p = 'z', d = 'a';
  // read sample data
  std::ifstream symbols("symbols.txt");
  for (char x; symbols >> x;) sym1.push_back(x);
  // move all characters in [d, p] to sym2
  size_t iWrite = 0;
  for (size_t iRead = 0, n = sym1.size(); iRead < n; ++iRead) {
    const char c = sym1[iRead];
    if (c >= d && c <= p) sym2.push_back(c);
    else sym1[iWrite++] = sym1[iRead];
  }
  // The difference between iWrite - iRead is the number of obsolete elements.
  // (It must be equal to sym2.size().)
  sym1.resize(iWrite);
  // could've been altermatively: sym1.erase(sym1.begin() + iWrite, sym1.end());
  // show results:
  std::cout << "sym1: '";
  for (const char c : sym1) std::cout << c;
  std::cout << "'\nsym2: '";
  for (const char c : sym2) std::cout << c;
  std::cout << "'\n";
}
```

Input:

I used the above source code as input (as the OP didn't expose the `symbols.txt` file).

Output:

```
sym1: '#<>#<>#<>(){::<>1,2;='',='';//::(".");(;>>;)1._();//[,]2_W=0;(_R=0,=1.();R<;++R){=1[R];(>=&&<=)2._();1[W++]=1[R];}//TW-R.//(I2.().)1.(1.()+W,1.());//:::<<"1:'";(:1)::<<;::<<"'\2:'";(:2)::<<;::<<"'\";}'
sym2: 'includefstreamincludeiostreamincludevectorintmainstdvectorcharsymsymconstcharpadzreadsampledatastdifstreamsymbolssymbolstxtforcharxsymbolsxsympushbackxmoveallcharactersindptosymsizetiriteforsizetieadnsymsizeieadnieadconstcharcsymieadifcpcdsympushbackcelsesymiritesymieadhedifferencebetweeniriteieadisthenumberofobsoleteelementstmustbeequaltosymsizesymerasesymbeginiritesymendshowresultsstdcoutsymforconstcharcsymstdcoutcstdcoutnsymforconstcharcsymstdcoutcstdcoutn'
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5003b213dbcf53e1)

So, for the range [`'a'`, `'z'`], (I used in my demo for better illustration) `sym2` ends up containing all lower case characters while `sym1` keeps everything else (except the white spaces).

Concerning the missing white spaces I wondered a bit until I realized that the white spaces are filtered out by the read loop:

```
for (char x; symbols >> x;) sym1.push_back(x);
```

which used formatted input.
This could be changed using `symbols.get(x)` instead of `symbols >> x` but the filtering of white space might be even intended.

---

Nitpicking:

OP described the range `[d;p]` (for the characters to move) as requirement.

AFAIK, it's usual that square brackets (or angle brackets) describe ranges with closed ends (i.e. with *inclusive* border values) while for open ends (*exclusive* border values) round brackets are used.

Thus, either the requirement has to be `(d;p)`
or the implementation of the range check

```
        if (sym1[i] < p && sym1[i] > d){ // check for range (d;p)
```

is not according to the requirement but should be

```
        if (sym1[i] <= p && sym1[i] >= d){ // check for range [d;p]
```